# Default value for a model validate rule

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3

I have a question regarding default values for model fields, this problem has been driving me crazy for a while.

To give you an example, I have a model with a status field that must be validated:

```
$validate = array (
    ...
    'status' => array(
        'list' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('0','1')),
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    )
)
```

The data that is inserted in the database is not submitted from a form.

If the status field is missing, I want it to default to 1, otherwise it must be validated.

Is there a way to do this from the model without using custom validation rules? I know I can set the default value in the MySQL table, but I still want to validate it from the model, in case a different value is submitted.

**EDIT**

I looked at the Validation class code and the inList validation is just a stupid wrapper for an in_array check:

**Cake.Utility.Validation.php**

```
public static function inList($check, $list, $strict = true) {
   return in_array($check, $list, $strict);
}
```

What do you know, there is also a third param that is not mentioned in the [`CakePHP Api docs`](http://api21.cakephp.org/class/validation#method-ValidationinList) ($strict), which defaults to true.

From the in_array docs:

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array()
>   function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

It still doesn't solve my problem, but now I know why array('inList', array('0','1')) was not validating empty fields even though allowEmpty was set to true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) method to set a default value.  Don't forget to return true or you will abort the save.

Comment: That might work, except it doesn't pass the validation rule, even though I have added 'allowEmpty' => true. I also tried: array('inList', array('','0','1')), but no luck so far.

Comment: How about beforeValidate().

Comment: Hmmm...isn't using beforeValidate() the same as adding a custom validation rule? However, I agree that there isn't any predefined way of adding default values, so I will go ahead with your suggestion and add a value in beforeSave(). I will also modify the inList rule like this: array('inList', array('0','1'), false), since otherwise it will not validate empty fields.